# iOS drawRect with custom height

Tags: ios, height, drawrect

I have placed a view on a viewController and I want to draw a rectangle in this view, but with a custom height. I determine the height based on a parameter in my viewController.
So for example. If my parameter is 50, I want the rectangle to have the height of 50% of the UIView.

2 questions:

- how can I pass the height to the custom drawRect?
- how do I make the rectangle be placed on the bottom of the UIView?

I have placed the view using Interface Builder and I have implemented the drawRect in a subclass of UIView and used this as Custom Class for my UIView.

So in the custom class I have:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIColor * lightGrayColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    CGRect paperRect =  self.bounds;

    drawLinearGradient(context, paperRect, lightGrayColor.CGColor, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);


}

void drawLinearGradient(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGColorRef startColor, CGColorRef endColor)
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat locations[] = { 0.0, 1.0 };

    NSArray *colors = @[(__bridge id) startColor, (__bridge id) endColor];

    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef) colors, locations);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

This draws a nice gradient rectangle in my view but it fills the complete UIView.
This is because of the self.bounds.

I have added a property *height to my custom class, but I don't know how to fill this from my viewController. So I want it to start at the bottom off the UIView, and make it as high as I have determined (a % of the real height).

Anybody knows how I can achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you add a subview (50% of current view), then fill that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you set your custom view class in identity inspector in interface builder?

you can set the height property from your viewController:

```
((MyViewClass *) self.myView).height = myCalculatedValue;
```

then implement drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIColor * lightGrayColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    CGRect paperRect =  self.bounds;
    paperRect.origin.y = paperRect.size.height - self.height;
    paperRect.size.height = self.height;
    //assuming your height property is of CGFloat type

    drawLinearGradient(context, paperRect, lightGrayColor.CGColor, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
}
```

this will draw your gradient from (height) points above the bottom to the bottom

Comment: Briljant! I had set the custom view class in the inspector, but I did not knew the (MyViewClass *) addition... Thank you very much!!!

Comment: you're welcome! if the type of the IBOutlet is set to MyViewClass you won't need the typecast.

Comment: Ah.... There's my mistake!!! I set it to UIView, not to the CustomView... *doh* Dubble points for this one please!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get calculate 50% of screen height and then substract new view height from the  full screen Height

```
youParameter = 50; // Lets assume this is your parametere

int heightOfView   = ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * yourParameter) / 100;

// For placing the view to the bottom;

CGRect newFrame;
frame.origin.y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - heightOfView;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.size.width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width; // assuming it will take full width
frame.size.height = heightOfView;

youViewToChange.frame = newFrame; // normally do this or
```

To pass the value to drawRect you can do:

```
[self drawRect:newFrame];
```

Comment: Hmm.. When I place this in my UIViewController, this makes the view also go smaller, but I want the view to stay the full height, but draw a rectangle within (or on-top) of this view. When I place this in the drawRect method, the rectangle has the new height, but then I don;t havemy paramater there...